# set server_name in Nginx based on global variable

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a server with nginx that runs a site in production that should be replaced with a new site in the near future.

In order to be ready to that day - I'm preparing all the configurations that are required to run the new site.

What I would like to have is a global variable in the main `nginx.conf` that hold a string (e.g. `'old'` or `'new'` representing the site that should be active on the main domain `example.com` while the other site is on `other.example.com`.

I tried:

### In `nginx.conf`

```
http{
    ...
    set $site_in_production 'new';
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.c/*.conf;
}
```

### In `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf`

```
server{
    ...
    if($site_in_production='new'){
         server_name other.example.com;
    } else {
         server_name example.com www.example.com;
    }
    ...
}
```

### In `/etc/nginx/conf.d/new.example.com.conf`

```
server{
    ...
    if($site_in_production='new'){
         server_name example.com www.example.com;
    } else {
         server_name other.example.com;
    }
    ...
}
```

But, when running a configtest I get this error:

```
 nginx: [emerg] "set" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:XX
```

so I guess that the `set` directive is not allowed outside of a `server` block

Is there a way to achieve this functionality with a single variable across all nginx config files??

Thank you very much!

Comment: No. What for? I guess it's much easier to replace config files when you'll need

Comment: if something like variables was possible - it would have been much easier changing `1` to `0` in one place instead of handling 4 different files (HTTP+HTTPS for both sites).

Answer (score 2):

Just make a script. Sure an elegant solution built into nginx would be nice... but let's not forget the tools *nix affords us:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
do
    sed -i 's/server_name example.com www.example.com;/server_name other.example.com;/g' "$i";
done
```

... You may have to escape those semicolons.. Not sure...

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying!
The script you wrote will make both files has the same server_name which will cause an error while trying to reload the server (it is easy to fix though).
But, I've tried to find a solution that doesn't involve changing the content of the *.conf files.